# How do I pass the ontap function

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How can I pass the ontap function to each icons

```
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[

      BottomNavigationBarItem(

        icon: Icon(Icons.call),

        label: 'Calls',

      ),

      BottomNavigationBa

    ],

    onTap: (i) {

     

    },
```

How.do i pass it to each items

Comment: you can use `  onTap: (i)` this `i`

Comment: I still have problems. Is it. Because of the stateless widget am using

Comment: are you trying to change the body based on tap index? it would be easier if you could describe what exactly are you trying to archive

Comment: I am trying to change it based on index. But you can recommend any method which will be better to me

Comment: are you using separate widget for BottonNavBar?

Comment: I am using BottomNavigationBar widget

Comment: you can follow the doc example as i've included link on my post

Answer (score 0):

```
items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[

  BottomNavigationBarItem(

    icon: Icon(Icons.call),

    label: 'Calls',

  ),

  BottomNavigationBarItem(

    icon: Icon(Icons.contacts),

    label: 'Contacts',

  ),

],

onTap: (i) {

  // call
  if( i == 0 ){
   // do somethings
  };

  // contacts
  if( i == 1 ){
   // do somethings
   };

},
```

Comment: I don't understand this bro. How do I apply this to icons

Comment: onTap(int index) give you touched index. you can get index and do what ever you want according to index number.  look at this link : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback method update widget based on tap,

You can follow this example code.

```dart
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavBar(
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = index;
            });
          }),
      body: Center(
        child: [Text('1'), Text('2'), Text('3')][currentIndex],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyBottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyBottomNavBar({
    super.key,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.currentIndex,
  });

  final Function(int) onTap;
  final int currentIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: currentIndex,
      onTap: onTap,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

If you are using on same widget, Follow [doc example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Comment: you could use more expressive https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueChanged.html instead of `Function`